# Improve performance of Android Universal Image Loader

Tags: android

I'm developing image loader related application.I want to load bulk of images.So I using **android Universal Image Loader**
The problem is first time loading taking too much time.After that perform fast..

I want to perform very fast as application loading time itself.Any one have idea please post..

Imageloader class  code look like this

```
    package com.primus.exploretaukymodule;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Imageadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> image_path;

    Context mcontext;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImageLoader load;




     static ImageLoaderConfiguration config ;



     static DisplayImageOptions imgDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
     //.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
     .cacheInMemory() 
     .cacheOnDisc() 
     //.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT) 
     .build();

     static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public Imageadapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> imageUrls, ImageLoader loader, DisplayImageOptions options) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        image_path=new ArrayList<String>();

        image_path=imageUrls;

        mcontext=c;

        inflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        load=loader;

        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
         .enableLogging()
         .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
         .discCacheSize(104857600)
         .threadPoolSize(10)
         .build();

         imageLoader.init(config);           


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return image_path.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;

         if (convertView == null) {

             holder=new ViewHolder();

             convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.explore_gridview_layout, parent, false);

             holder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taukytab_grid_image);

             convertView.setTag(holder);


         } 
         else {

             holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }


         holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

         imageLoader.displayImage(image_path.get(position),holder.imageView, imgDisplayOptions);

         return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

isn't that because of cache? If so then to load faster you need faster Internet connection or store images in assets and check if they're there before loading them from the net.

Comment: Thanks for replay..yes definitely my images load from the web..I want to know any updates of my code that perform fast  or not???